# Any way to provide hadoop as Source in spring-cloud-dataflow

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

Is there a way to provide **hadoop** as **Source** in spring-cloud-dataflow ?

I have read the documentation of spring-cloud-dataflow and found that it supports **hadoop** as **Sink** only.
But I need to run a map-reduce job that will read data from hdfs , do aggregation and transformations upon data and finally store data to hdfs.
So , kindly provide a way to handle the above situation.